# Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'. Kotlin could not find the required JDK tools in the Java installation

Tags: android, flutter, android-emulator

when I run my flutter app it show this problem , ( I am using Genymotion as emulator )

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.

> Kotlin could not find the required JDK tools in the Java installation 'C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\jre' used by Gradle. Make sure Gradle is running on a JDK, not JRE.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 31s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                             32.6s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

what is the relation between Kotlin and flutter , why dose it appear here ? I did not use kotlin

I deleted the old version of java and installed the new version , and also  I tried to put java jdk inside the android folder but it still dose not work

Comment: could you run `flutter doctor -v` in the terminal and upload the result in the question please?

Answer (score 0):

To quote from the [flutter docs](https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/kotlin-version)

> To build a Flutter app for Android, Kotlin 1.5.31 or greater is required

Flutter itself is a UI framework with its own rendering engine embedded on top of the different platforms it supports (iOS, Android, web, ...). While coding in Dart, you might not see the lower layers, but deep down the engine still runs on top of the platforms. So even if you do not write Kotlin code yourself, Kotlin is one of the lower level dependencies of a flutter app on Android.

To check that you have all the dependencies installed and correctly setup, you can use `flutter doctor` on your command line.